# How to make Page background Light in color

Tags: pdftex, color, pagecolor

Hi i am looking for Light colors for the page background.
here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{Dandelion}
\color{Violet}
\Large
$$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
\end{document}
```

My output is shown below:

[image]

How to reduce brightness of the above color?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, BTW --- and a tip, `[12pt]` should come before `{article}`, not after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could mix it with white (or any other color really), for instance, using `Dandelion!20!white` ("20" here means 20% Dandelion, with the rest being white):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{Dandelion!20!white}
\color{Violet}
\Large
$$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Have a look at the [`xcolor` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) as well.

Comment: Can this mixing be done with any two colors or only with white?

Comment: @Umeshshankar You can use any colors, and you're not limited to two either.